# Plural of Hercules

Tags: plural-forms, orthography

I was reading a question in aviation.se and there were multiple planes. There were several planes with the designation of P-3 Orion, so it was worded Orions. There were several planes with the designation F-18 Hornet. So they were Hornets.

Then there were several planes with the designation C-130 Hercules. The author said there were several Herculess. But that looks wrong, and I couldn't figure out how to correct the following sentence:
"Apple Maps showed some C-130 Herculess, F-18 Hornets, P-3 Orions, and a few other aircraft."

At first, I changed Herculess to Hercules, but the name IS "Hercules", so how do we say it in plural form?

Comment: This doesn’t really answer your question, but informally they are referred to as ‘hercs’ which simplifies pluralizing it.

Comment: The plural of *species* is *species*, so I'd be tempted to leave *Hercules* similarly unchanged in the plural.

Comment: In January 2017, the German defence minister announced the intention to purchase 3 C-130J and 3 KC-130J Hercules (Wikipedia)

Answer (score 1):

I am not at all familiar with Greek, but [this site](https://www.greekboston.com/learn-speak/masculine-plurals/) says "Words ending in ές (es) turns into έδες (ethes)." So the plural would be "Herculethes"—but, being a proper name, it very well could be irregular.

In Latin, **Hercules** is third declension. The nominative plural is also "Hercules." This is what I would suggest as the most likely candidate.

It is also possible to take **Hercules** as a loanword and apply standard English pluralization: "s" or "es" depending on if the word ends in "s" or not. This would give "Herculeses" (which my spell check does not recognize).

Answer (score -2):

Well in answer to your question and I am no expert on the plural forms of Greek words. All I was able to find is this

> **Adding the Ending s/es to Nouns and Verbs**
> The material below describes the rules of adding the ending s/es to the final consonants and vowels of nouns and verbs.

**The ending s/es is added to nouns to form regular plural forms of nouns**

Ref [Useful English](https://usefulenglish.ru/writing/adding-endings-s-es-to-nouns-and-verbs)

> **Names:**
> If names or family names end in **s**, z, x, ch, tch, sh, **the ending ES is added to form the plural**; the ending S is added to the final mute E after these letters and to ce, dge, ge. **The ending s/es is pronounced [iz] in these cases.**

For example: Morris – two Morrises; Max – three Maxes;

Therefore I would presume you have multiple C-130 Herculeses (Hercules-**iz**)